# Cant get values by choosing specific row in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

i have a picker view with array of countries, and my point is, when user tap a specific row i will write some code depends of elements user choose, but, somehow its not working, please look at this:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

   if ([countries objectAtIndex:0]){
        NSLog(@"You selected USA");
    } 
}
```

But problem is, in NSLog is always "You selected USA", regardless of which row i have pick. But, when i put that line of code here:

```
  NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [countries objectAtIndex:row]);
```

It show me in console which of country i have choose. But i need to do a things when user tap specific row, and i cant understand how to do this, please help me.

Comment: `if ([countries objectAtIndex:0])` will allways evaluate to TRUE/YES unless the object at the first index (index 0) of the array countries happens to be null. Use `if (row == 0)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: you should use

`if ([[countries objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"USA"]) ...`

Nice answer:

Define an enum and use switch-case structure:

```
// put this in the header before @interface - @end block

enum {
    kCountryUSA     = 0, // pay attention to use the same 
    kCountryCanada  = 1, // order as in countries array
    kCountryFrance  = 2,
    // ...
    };

// in the @implementation:

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
     didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (row) {
        case kCountryUSA:
            NSLog(@"You selected USA");
            break;

        case kCountryCanada:
            NSLog(@"You selected Canada");
            break;

        case kCountryFrance:
            NSLog(@"You selected France");
            break;

            //...

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown selection");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i do this, how could i assign some variable when user chose USA, or Germany for example? I guess i need if statement.

Comment: Ok, now I understand better your problem, I updated my answer.